# set oracle schema in shell script

Tags: oracle, shell, sqlplus

I have a shell script inside which i am calling oracle packages/functions/procedure and all these oracle objects present in schema `test3` in server `x`. I have a private user/password `apple/orange` to connect to server `x`.User `apple` has permission to access objects from schema `test3`for which i need to set the current schema as `test3` in shell script using below code

```
sqlplus -s apple/orange <<EOF
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE
set linesize 80
set pages 0
set echo off
set feed off
set feedback off
set term off
set verify off
ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = test3;
exit;
EOF
```

But this code is not setting up the schema.

Can you please help.

Comment: What do you expect that script do do? After changing the current schema you immediately exit the script and don't do anything "within" the schema.

Comment: you have changed the schema, all instructions after the **set current_schema** will be executed in schema **test3**

Comment: once i set the schema i need to run set of queries and procedures/functions. And i wanted set this schema globally i.e. throughout the shell execution/run.

Comment: You can't. The `ALTER SESSION` is only for that _session_ which is the same as the current connection. If you end that connection, you end that session.